# I don't know why the instance method turned to be NilClass when it is called in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am probably misunderstanding the concept of method and I want your help if you are willing to.

I am facing the problem that this method below returns String perfectly, but when I try to use it in a method in a different class, it returns NilClass.

```
class FruitConverter
     def fruit_converter(fruit)
        return if fruit.nil?
        find_favorite_fruit = list.find{|k,v| k == fruit}
        find_favorite_fruit         ← when I print it it returns "りんご" if fruit == "apple"
     end

     def list
        {
           "りんご" : "とっても美味しいりんご",
           "オレンジ" : "とっても美味しいオレンジ"
        }
     end
end
```

↑this works fine here but when I use it in a method in a different class, the result turned to be NilClass like this.

```
def fruit
    fav_fruit = @target_person.fruit
    fruit = FruitConverter.new.fruit_converter(fruit)
    fruit           ←when print fruit.class it returns nilClass.
end
```

I have a bunch of almost same instance methods and those could work. One of them is like this.

```
class SizeConverter
     def size_converter(size)
        return if size.nil?
        find_size = list.find{|k,v| k == size.to_sym}
        find_size         
     end

     def list
        {
           small : "Ohkii",
           medium : "chukurai"
        }
     end
end
```

this works fine. so maybe the error of the first code is because of its result.
but I don't know how to fix it.

I would love you to tell me any clues.
Thank you.

Comment: You can just use `list.index(value)` instead of `find`.

Comment: Thank you so much! my code looks clean now. but I still got the nilClass. Do you know why ?

Comment: No - nobody can actually answer this question without knowing what `@target_person.fruit` returns.

Comment: Are you passing the fruit correctly?  `fruit = FruitConverter.new.fruit_converter(fav_fruit)` ?

Comment: yes, I am passing the fruit correctly. I think that is why I can get the correct result in the fruit_converter(fruit) method. I came to think that I don't initialize in the FruitConverter class. Can it be a reason of the problem?

Comment: I am sorry. the problem occurred just because the data is really nil. it the data sent was correct it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry. It seems that there is no problem in the beginning.
the only problem was that I gave a fruit that is not existing in the list to fruit_converter. That is why it returns nil. But when I gave true fruit it worked. Thank you all anyways.